# MPI_Pack & MPI_Unpack sent and received size

Tags: c, mpi

I have to send a struct with, among others, two dynamic array inside and I decided to use the MPI_Pack and MPI_Unpack solution.

I wrote the following code that makes what I need, but I'm not satisfied because I have to use a constant value `MAX_BUFF_SIZE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 1000

typedef struct Data {
    int elemsNr;
    int charsNr;
    int *elements;
    char *chars;
} Data;

int getRand(int from, int to)
{
    int num = (rand() % (to - from + 1)) + from;
    return num;
}

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int procNumber;
    int pid; 

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procNumber);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);

    if (procNumber < 2) {
        printf("At least two processes required.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const int from = 1;
    const int to = 9;

    srand(time(0));

    Data data = {.elemsNr = 0, .charsNr = 0, .elements = NULL, .chars = NULL};

    int pos = 0;
    int size = 0;

    if (pid == 0) {
        size += sizeof(int) * 3;

        // create some fake values
        data.elemsNr = getRand(from, to);
        data.elements = calloc(data.elemsNr, sizeof(int));

        size += sizeof(int) * data.elemsNr;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.elemsNr; i++)
            data.elements[i] = getRand(from, to);

        data.charsNr = getRand(from, to);
        data.chars = calloc(data.charsNr, sizeof(char));

        size += sizeof(char) * data.charsNr;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.charsNr; i++)
            data.chars[i] = getRand('a', 'z');

        printf("source data\n");
        printf("Size of the struct: %d\n", size);
        printf("data.elemsNr: %d\n", data.elemsNr);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.elemsNr; i++)
            printf("data.elements[%d]: %d\n", i, data.elements[i]);

        printf("data.charsNr: %d\n", data.charsNr);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.charsNr; i++)
            printf("data.chars[%d]: %d\n", i, data.chars[i]);

        // allocate memory of the pack buffer
        char *buff = calloc(size, sizeof(char));

        MPI_Pack(&data.elemsNr, 1, MPI_INT, buff, size, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(&data.charsNr, 1, MPI_INT, buff, size, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(data.elements, data.elemsNr, MPI_INT, buff, size, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(data.chars, data.charsNr, MPI_CHAR, buff, size, &pos, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(buff, pos, MPI_PACKED, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        free(buff);
    } else {
        MPI_Status status;
        char *buff = calloc(MAX_BUFF_SIZE, sizeof(char));

        MPI_Recv(buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, MPI_PACKED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        MPI_Unpack(buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, &pos, &data.elemsNr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Unpack(buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, &pos, &data.charsNr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        data.elements = calloc(data.elemsNr, sizeof(int));
        MPI_Unpack(buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, &pos, data.elements, data.elemsNr, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        data.chars = calloc(data.charsNr, sizeof(char));
        MPI_Unpack(buff, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, &pos, data.chars, data.charsNr, MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("destination data\n");
        printf("Size of the struct: %d\n", size);
        printf("data.elemsNr: %d\n", data.elemsNr);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.elemsNr; i++)
            printf("data.elements[%d]: %d\n", i, data.elements[i]);
        
        printf("data.charsNr: %d\n", data.charsNr);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.charsNr; i++)
            printf("data.chars[%d]: %d\n", i, data.chars[i]);

        free(buff);
    }

    free(data.chars);
    free(data.elements);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Is there a way to avoid to use `MAX_BUFF_SIZE` and compute the size dynamically on receive side?

Otherwise, could be a solution sending first a message with the size and then the packed message?

Comment: Sending the size first is an option. An other is to `MPI_Probe()` to get the message size, and then allocate and `MPI_Recv()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following [Gilles Gouaillardet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet)'s the suggestion:

> Sending the size first is an option. An other is to MPI_Probe() to get the message size, and then allocate and MPI_Recv().

I decided to use the MPI_Probe() solution.

Here below my solution.

```
// previous code

} else {
  MPI_Status status;
  int bufferSize = 0;

  MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_PACKED, &bufferSize);
  char *buff = calloc(bufferSize, sizeof(char));

  MPI_Recv(buff, bufferSize, MPI_PACKED, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

  MPI_Unpack(buff, bufferSize, &pos, &data.elemsNr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Unpack(buff, bufferSize, &pos, &data.charsNr, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  data.elements = calloc(data.elemsNr, sizeof(int));
  MPI_Unpack(buff, bufferSize, &pos, data.elements, data.elemsNr, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  data.chars = calloc(data.charsNr, sizeof(char));
  MPI_Unpack(buff, bufferSize, &pos, data.chars, data.charsNr, MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  free(buff)
}

// following code
```